# Why I need use encoding in String.getBytes(charsetName)

Tags: java

Ususally when I need to convert my string to `byte[]` I use `getBytes()` without param. I was checked it is not save I should use charset. Why I shoud do so - letter 'A' will always be parsed to `0x41`? Is't it?

Comment: Read up on character sets: [Character_encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding). _letter 'A' will always be parsed to 0x41? Is't it?_ No, not necessarily.

Comment: Different encodings interpret same set of bytes in different manner.

Comment: When in doubt, don't assume. If a parameter has a role, understanding its use means understanding the whole concept behind him. As @SotiriosDelimanolis suggested, check that link. You should *Never* give anything for granted when it comes to conversions, serialization and parsing.

Answer (score 4):

> Ususally when I need to convert my string to byte[] I use getBytes() without param.

Stop doing that *right now*. I would suggest that you *always* specify an encoding. If you want to use the platform default encoding (which is what you'll get if you don't specify one), then do that explicitly so that it's clearer. But that should *very rarely* be the approach anyway. Personally I use UTF-8 in almost all cases.

> Why I shoud do so - letter 'A' will always be parsed to 0x41? Is't it?

Nope. For example, using UTF-16, 'A' will be two bytes - 0x41 0x00 or 0x00 0x41 (depending on the endianness). In EBCDIC encodings it could be something completely different.

*Most* encodings treat ASCII characters in the same way - but characters outside ASCII are represented very differently in different encodings (and many encodings only support a subset of Unicode).

See my [article on Unicode](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Unicode.aspx) (C#-focused, but the principles are the same) for a few more details - and links to more information than you're ever likely to want.

Answer (score 1):

Different character encodings lead to different ways characters get parsed. In Ascii, sure 'A' will parse to 0x41. In other encodings, this will be different.

This is why when you go to some webpages, you may see a bunch of weird characters. The browser doesn't know how to decode it, so it just decodes to the default.

Answer (score 0):

Some background: When text is stored in files or sent between computers over a socket, the text characters are stored or sent as a sequence of bits, almost always grouped in 8-bit bytes.  The characters all have defined numeric values in Unicode, so that 'A' always has the value 0x41 (well, there are actually two other A's in the Unicode character set, in the Greek and Russian alphabets, but that's not relevant).  But there are many mechanisms for *how* those numeric codes are translated to a sequence of bits when storing in a file or sending to another computer.  In UTF-8, 0x41 is represented as 8 bits (the byte 0x41), but other numeric values (code points) will be converted to 16 or more bits with an algorithm that rearranges the bits; in UTF-16, 0x41 is represented as 16 bits; and there are other encodings like JIS and some which are capable of representing some but not all of the Unicode characters.  Since `String.getBytes()` was intended to return a byte array that contains the bytes to be sent to a file or socket, the method needs to know what encoding it's supposed to use when creating those bytes.  Basically the encoding will have to be the same one that a program later reading a file, or a computer at the other end of the socket, expects it to be.